# Find the maximun of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(f(k))-f(k))$

Tags: functions, optimization, summation

Let $f:\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}\to \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ such that
$$f(1)\le f(2)\le\cdots\le f(n)$$
Let $g(n)$
$$g(n)=max\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(f(k))-f(k))\right)$$
Find $$g(n)$$

Comment: $nf(f(n))-nf(1)$.

Comment: I think the maximum would be the same as maximum of $\sum_{k=1}^n((f(k)-k)$

Comment: I can get a sum of $20$ (two ways)

Comment: @SayantanSantra The maximum is certainly not attained for the *same* function $f$ then

Comment: @Henry for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: For $f(k)$ equal ${n \over 2} + 1$ for range first half, $n$ for second we have ${n^2 \over 4} - {n \over 2}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: sorry - I was considering $n=10$. More generally I think I can achieve $\lceil \frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{n}{2}\rceil$

Comment: @Abstraction: That $f$ does not satisfy the given inequalities and does not take natural values.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: That is an upper bound, but not necessary the maximum. How do find an $f$ producing precisely that value?

Comment: Working it out by brute force on Maple, the answers for $n=3,\ldots,11$ are $1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25$.  The pattern seems clear... but how to prove it ;-)

Comment: @David the pattern is not *completely* clear to me.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Start with $1$ then add $1,2,2,3,3,4,4,\ldots\,$.

Comment: @David So the answer involves $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, right? Can you tell us the functions $f=f_n$ attaining these maximum values? Thanks.

Comment: @David Perhaps I was not clear enough: does you Maple program keep track of the functions $f$? in this way you can determine for which functions $f=f_n$ (hopefully a unique one) the maximum value is attained, and this can be helpful in order to prove some definitive statement.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Sorry but I seem to have deleted the Maple file - had a good look but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

My best effort:

Let $m=\lceil \frac{n+1}{2}\rceil$. So $m=\frac{n+1}{2}$ for odd $n$, and $m=\frac{n+2}{2}$ for even $n$.

Then let $f(k)=m$ for $1 \le k \lt m$ and $f(k)=n$ for $m \le k \le n$. In particular $f(m)=f(n)=n$.

In this case $f(f(k))=n$ for all $k$ and so $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (f(f(k))-f(k)) = (m-1)(n-m).$

For odd $n$ this gives $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (f(f(k))-f(k)) = \left(\frac{n=1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{n}{2}+\frac14.$

For even $n$ this gives $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (f(f(k))-f(k)) = \frac{n}{2}   \times \frac{n-2}{2}= \frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{n}{2}.$

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proof but I presume this may be the maximum.

Assume
$$f(k)=\min (k+d,n)\quad(d\ge1)$$
Then
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n (f(f(k))-f(k))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f(f(k))-\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f(\min (k+d,n))-\sum_{k=1}^n\min (k+d,n))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \min(\min (k+d,n)+d,n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\min (k+d,n))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-d} \min(k+2d,n)+\sum_{k=n-d+1}^{n}\min(n+d,n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-d} (k+d)-\sum_{k=n-d+1}^{n}n\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2d} (k+2d)+\sum_{k=n-2d+1}^{n} n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-d} (k+d)-\sum_{k=n-d+1}^{n}n\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2d} d+\sum_{k=n-2d+1}^{n-d}(n-(k+d))\\
&=(n-2d)d+d(n-d)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-d}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2d+1}k\\
&=2nd-3d^2-\frac{(n-d)(n-d+1)}2+\frac{(n-2d)(n-2d+1)}2\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)d-3d^2}{2}\\
&=\frac{-3\left(d-\left(\frac{2n-1}{6}\right)\right)^2+3\left(\frac{2n-1}{6}\right)^2}{2}\\
&\le \frac{(2n-1)\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{6}\rfloor-3\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{6}\rfloor^2}{2}
\end{align}